# On clicked TableView row set text to Lables

Tags: java, javafx, binding

How can I on clicked worker in `TableView` row, update text to `Lables` in the following `Scene`:

[image]

This is my method for setting text to Lables, but I don't know how to bind them together.

```
@FXML private void rowSelected(){
    selectedItems =  radniciTabela.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    ime.setText(selectedItems.getIme());
    prezime.setText(selectedItems.getPrezime());
    godine.setText(selectedItems.getGodište());
    grad.setText(selectedItems.getGrad());
    adresa.setText(selectedItems.getAdresa());
    telefon.setText(selectedItems.getTelefon());
    email.setText(selectedItems.getMejl());}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use there the `@FXML` annotation, you have to add a listener to your `TableView`'s selection model this way:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(newValue != null){
            rowSelected(newValue);
        }
    });
```

And you can remove the `selectedItems =  radniciTabela.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` line from your method and add as parameter.

Comment: It gives me an Exeption

Comment: What exception? Can you copy and paste it here?

Comment: I got it now. I just needed listener on selected row to retrieve data from Database. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the change listener and access to all the data in row like:

Here replacing T with class you used in table view

```
 radniciTabela.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<T>() {
                @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observableValue, T oldValue,
                        T newValue) {
          if(newValue != null){
                ime.setText(newValue.getIme());
                prezime.setText(newValue.getPrezime());
                godine.setText(newValue.getGodište());
                grad.setText(newValue.getGrad());
                adresa.setText(newValue.getAdresa());
                telefon.setText(newValue.getTelefon());
                email.setText(newValue.getMejl());
           }
        }
    });
```